# how to turn off the Camera Light while taking snap programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, macos, camera

I'm developing one app in which **i want to capture an image at run time.**
It has to work for both **MAC PRO & Mac mini (If web cam is connected)**. When Camera takes picture **small light** will come at the time of taking snap, that should not come. Its not regarding the **flash.**

**code snippet:**

```
- (void)captureOutput:(QTCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputVideoFrame:(CVImageBufferRef)videoFrame withSampleBuffer:(QTSampleBuffer *)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(QTCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    // If we already have an image we should use that instead
    if ( currentImage ) return;

    // Retain the videoFrame so it won't disappear
    // don't forget to release!
    CVBufferRetain(videoFrame);

    // The Apple docs state that this action must be synchronized
    // as this method will be run on another thread
    @synchronized (self) {
        currentImage = videoFrame;
    }

    // As stated above, this method will be called on another thread, so
    // we perform the selector that handles the image on the main thread
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(saveImage) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

To capture picture i'm using the above method. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hm, now what would you want to do that? Maybe to hide the fact that the camera is in use? In all likelihood the light turns on automatically when the camera is active and to change that you would have to alter the firmware of the camera itself.

Comment: just i want to turn off the light during my application runs...

Comment: A Mac Pro has no build in camera, are you talking about a MacBook Pro? Is yes the is you don't what the camera active light to turn green you will need to hack the driver. The light is there to make the user aware that the camera is used. Turning it off looks really suspicious, like you want to take image/video secretly.

Comment: But in my application i want to make it off without user aware. Any API that we can achieve through that

Comment: @YogeeshHT No, there is no API that provides a way to take a picture without alerting the user.  That's the whole point of the light, and why it is implemented in firmware (or hardware, possibly, in more recent models).

Answer (score 2):

According to [this article](http://lowendmac.com/2013/disabling-isight-led-i-spy-with-my-little-isight/), several older MacBooks' camera LEDs could be circumvented by tying into the circuit board logic directly.

To my knowledge, there is no longer this security loophole, nor is there an API available in Objective-C to disable the camera LED.